# crate casbin policy for specific need

Tags: go, casbin

1. Is it possible to have policy which grant read read access to all resource except for specific one.
   My current policy is:

```
p, read_some, data1, read
p, read_all, data2, read
p, read_all, data3, read

g, read_all, read_some
```

2. Is it possible to grant read access for specific resource if have write access?
   My current policy is:

```
p, view_only_user, data1, read
p, write_user, data1, write

g, write_user, view_only_user
```

Comment: Plz use keyMatch() or regexMatch() in matcher.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: plz send a github issue